# Specify API View methods in urls

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

So, I have a view that inherits from APIView, I've defined get, post and delete methods.

My urls.py:

```
path('projects/', projects.ProjectView.as_view()),
path('projects/create/', projects.ProjectsView.as_view()
```

But right now I can make a request with any method accessing these API's. For example, I can create a project going to 'projects/' and I can delete a project going to 'projects/create/'.

Is there a way to specify what methods I wanna use for a specific url? When a user goes to 'projects/' I want only the 'get' method to be allowed for this url.

Comment: Post your `serializers` and `views` code.

Answer (score 2):

On classy way to do it is to inherit from [generic-view](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/)

Your `ProjectView` should inherit from `RetrieveAPIView` and `ProjectsVIew` from `CreateAPIView`

And you could probably rename your views to something more explicit.